# android Studio how to draw a game?

Tags: java, android

Im trying to create a Tic Tac Toe Game. everything works fine and if player 
 x or O  wins a message is showing and saying X or O won the game but the problem is  when there is no winner i should get a message saying "There is no winner try again".If you could help me with it you are making my day.

```
int activePlayer = 0; // for x player

int[] gameState ={2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2}; // 2 means unplayed.

int[][] winningLocation ={{0,1,2},{3,4,5},{6,7,8},{0,3,6},{1,4,7},{2,5,8},{0,4,8},{2,4,6}};
boolean gameover =false;

public void gameLogic(View view){

    ImageView tappedView =(ImageView) view;

    int tappedLocation = Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString());

    if(gameState[tappedLocation]==2 && !gameover) {
        gameState[tappedLocation]=activePlayer;

        tappedView.setTranslationY(-3000f);

        if (activePlayer == 0) {

            tappedView.setImageResource(R.drawable.x);

            activePlayer = 1;

        } else if (activePlayer == 1) {
            tappedView.setImageResource(R.drawable.o);
            activePlayer = 0;
        }
        tappedView.animate().translationYBy(3000f).setDuration(500);
    }

    String mesg ="";

    for(int[]winningPostion :winningLocation){

        if(gameState[winningPostion[0]] == gameState [winningPostion[1]]
                && gameState[winningPostion[1]]== gameState [winningPostion[2]]
                && gameState[winningPostion[0]]!=2){

            if (activePlayer ==0)

                mesg = "O is the winner!";

            if(activePlayer==1)

                mesg = "X is the winner!";

            else if(activePlayer==2)

                mesg="there is no winner";





            LinearLayout winnerLayout =(LinearLayout)findViewById (R.id.winnerLayout);
            winnerLayout.setVisibility(View .VISIBLE);

            TextView winnermesg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText);
            winnermesg.setText(mesg);

            gameover=true;
        }
    }




}

// a method that let the players play again

public void playagain(View view){
    LinearLayout winnerLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.winnerLayout);
    winnerLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    gameover=false;
    activePlayer=0;

    for (int i =0; i < gameState.length;i++)
        gameState[i]=2;

    GridLayout gridlayout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridlayout);
    for(int i =0 ; i < gridlayout.getChildCount(); i++)
        ((ImageView)gridlayout.getChildAt(i)).setImageResource(0);
}












@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);







 // to play the song
      mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.song);
      mediaPlayer.start();


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // to show and hide the playing again button

   LinearLayout winnerLayout = ( LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.winnerLayout);
    winnerLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);





   FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}





@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: I would imagine you haven't learned how to debug your app, otherwise you could step through the code and know exactly what the variable values are and figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Thank you for  taking your time and write me back  i did use debugging but i did not understand much im really stuck with that and im new with android studio .